# How to change plot's border style?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to change the border style of my plot.
By default it is plain black.
But what if I want a blue dash-dotted one of 10pt linewidth? (it's just an example).
Below a code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[domain = 1:10]{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify it in the optional argument of your `\addplot` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[blue, dashdotted, line width=3pt, domain = 1:10]{x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Note that I chose 3pt linewidth as it does not look that much bloated.

###### Edit

In case you are talking about the box around your plot, you can do nearly the same: Add `[blue, dashdotted, line width=3pt]` after `\begin{axis}`.